# About Method Overloading in Java

Tags: java, methods, overloading, overriding

Can method overloading take place only within the same class? Or can it take place within sub classes?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction on overloading within sub-classes. For example, I could have:

```
public class A {
 public String test(String input) {
  //do something
 }
}

public class B extends A {
 public String test(String input, String input2) {
  //do something
 }
}

B testInstance = new B();
testInstance.test("one", "two");
testInstance.test("one");
```

For questions like this, you can always try it yourself and find out.

Answer (score 1):

In a word - yes. You can overload methods in a subclass. E.g.:

```
public class Parent {
    public void print(String s) {
        System.out.println("That was a string: " + s);
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public void print(int i) {
        System.out.println("That was an int: " + i);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.print("hello"); // prints "That was a string: hello"
        c.print(7); // prints "That was an int: 7"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**When you overload a method, it's basically creating an entirely new method with no direct association with the other of the same name, it's the signature that matters.**
so if you make a method in the subclass that has different signature it will be treated as different and new method for that class by the compiler so it won't be relating it to the method of super class.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading can be possible in sub classes. If you create a method with the same name as in super class with different parameter then it will be treated as separate method. Sub class will have methods from super class as well so which method to be called is decided at compile time based on the parameter type. Which method to be called is declared at compile time that is why it's called static polymorphism. Here is the example -

```
Class A{
    void m1(int x){
        System.out.println("m1 in A");
    }
}
Class B extends A
{
   void m1(String str)
   {
       System.out.println("m1 in B");
   }
}
Public Class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] aa)
   {
       B b = new B();
       b.m1(10);
       b.m1("Hello World!!")
   }
}
```

Hope this will help.